# Stream cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a script that looks at all the files in a given directory, takes each of their paths, and prints it to screen. Whenever I run my program it says stream cannot be resolved to a type. I know the error has something to do with my variable type but I do not know what to change my variable type to. Any help is appreciated.

My Code:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.stream.Stream;

class FileFinder{
    

    public void getFiles(){
        Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/MYNAME/Documents/TestFiles");
        
        Stream<Path> subPaths = Files.walk(path);
        subPaths.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "getFiles" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Stream cannot be resolved to a type

        at FileFinder.getFiles(FileFinder.java:12)
```

Comment: Don't try to run a program that failed to compile. **Look at the compilation error** produced by the compiler, since it is a lot more descriptive than the error you get trying to run the code.

Comment: `import java.util.Stream;`...

Comment: @Eugene The [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) interface is in package `java.util.stream`, so it should be **`import java.util.stream.Stream;`**, but you're right, the problem is with the `import` statement.

Comment: The import was the issue, didn't spot it haha. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

## Wrong `Stream`

You have an import for `java.nio.stream.Stream`. But you need an import for `java.util.stream.Stream`.

The Javadoc for [`Files.walk`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...)) tells us the method returns a [`java.util.stream.Stream<Path>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) object.

```java
import java.util.stream.Stream;
```

## Closing I/O streams

By the way, that `Stream` object implements [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). So you can use try-with-resources syntax to make sure it is closed properly, one way or another.

While closing some kinds of streams may be unnecessary, ones involving I/O should be closed. I assume this includes your `Files.walk` stream.

To quote the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) interface Javadoc:

> Most stream instances do not actually need to be closed after use, as they are backed by collections, arrays, or generating functions, which require no special resource management. Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel, such as those returned by Files.lines(Path), will require closing. If a stream does require closing, it must be opened as a resource within a try-with-resources statement or similar control structure to ensure that it is closed promptly after its operations have completed.

## Basic code sample

```java
        Path path = Paths.get( "/Users/basilbourque/stuff" );
        try (
                Stream < Path > subPaths = Files.walk( path ) ;
        )
        {
            subPaths.forEach( System.out :: println );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

## Full sample code app

Here is a complete app, including the `import` statements.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FileFinder
{
    public void walkFiles ( )
    {
        Path path = Paths.get( "/Users/basilbourque/stuff" );
        try (
                Stream < Path > subPaths = Files.walk( path ) ;
        )
        {
            subPaths.forEach( System.out :: println );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        FileFinder app = new FileFinder();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        this.walkFiles();
    }
}
```

When run:

```
/Users/basilbourque/stuff
/Users/basilbourque/stuff/some_text.txt
/Users/basilbourque/stuff/slow-draft.txt
/Users/basilbourque/stuff/text.txt
```